# Getting audio feedback from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos

Sometimes Eclipse takes a really long time to do stuff. I might tab out to another application, get distracted by web sites with names that rhyme with *"flak clover show"*, and completely forget that I had something to pay attention to. It happens daily.

Is there any way to make Eclipse play a sound (acceptable alternative: bounce the dock icon in OS X) when a long-running tasks is completed? I'm thinking specifically of things that show up in the *Progress* view, like deploying to Tomcat:

[image: progress view example screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

With Eclipse WTP, you can enable audio feedback for several server-related events in workspace preferences / Server / Audio panel.

Comment: Oh awesome, this looks perfect.

Comment: Have you gotten to actually work on OS X? So far, I can point WTP at a `.wav.` or `.au` file, but can't get it to actually _play_ - not even in the Preferences window. `:(`

Comment: @MattBall late comment but future reference: right click server, switch location worked for me after this error.

Comment: @HRgiger 's fix worked for me. Specifically, right-click --> properties --> Switch Location (mine now says workspace metadata). Then I also had to make sure the yellow "grouping line" in the Audio preference menu was checked above and in addition to the notification(s) I wanted, select the "Enable Sounds" check box, and set the volume above 0.

Comment: Not only did HRgiger's suggestion not help for me, but it broke my Tomcat. Even after doing Switch location a second time, it wouldn't launch properly anymore.

I had to reconfigure the classpath to fix. I gave up on trying to get the sound to work with Eclipse 2023-03 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can always submit a bug (which can be a feature not a real bug) to eclipse's bugzilla. It would definitely be considered.

Open source contribution does not mean you need to contribute code, you can also contribute by submitting bugs or ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I'm well aware of the open-source environment. That's really not what I was asking, though.

Comment: It is a good idea thats why i asked you to submit. I am an eclipse committer and would gladly add if it is accepted.

Comment: As Eugene answered, it appears to already be a part of WTP, and that's really what I'm most interested. Now, to actually get it to _work_